# Understanding Algorithms in Javasciprt

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

I started to learn Algorithms in Javascript and I found a weird structure called hashtable on it that has not been possible to understand under the hood.

```
function findSumBetter(arr, weight) {
    var hashtable = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var currentElement = arr[i],
        difference = weight - currentElement;

        if (hashtable[currentElement] != undefined) {
            return [i, hashtable[currentElement]];
        } else {
            hashtable[difference] = i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

console.log(findSumBetter([1,2,3,4,5], 9)); // [4, 3]
```

Comment: Can anyone explain me please what do these three things do on the object ?  hashTable[currentElement]
,   [i, hashtable[currentElement]],  
 hashtable[difference] = i

Comment: Go through this overview of working with objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects Note the different syntax used `[]` for accessing properties with either string values or variables

Comment: The term hashtable in this case is nothing more than an object literal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay here is easy example:
 Let say you have JSON Object

```
Assigning value 
 1 ) hashtable:{'Test1':90,'test2':45,'test3':60};
 // here Test1,Test2,Test3 are keyes
 2 ) hashtable['test1']=90
Getting value:

 1) hashtable['Test1'] 
 2) hashtable.test1  
Both will return the same result 90 in this example.
```

--------In your case -------

```
 -- condition to check value is there 
  if (hashtable[currentElement] != undefined)
 -- you are assigning value to object
   hashtable[difference] = i;
 -- returning the value from object
   return [i, hashtable[currentElement]];
```

Comment: If hashTable[difference] is assigning values to hashTable object, what is actually  hashTable[currentElement] doing or evaluating in order to accomplish the condition when it is != undefined??

Comment: hashTable[currentElement] !- undefined : means condition to check a value exist for a paarticlur key, if key exist this return value otherwise undefined. let  say in my example above hashtable['test5'] this will return value undefined since we have not been assigned any 'test5' key to object.